# Spring boot create database view for entity

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, database-view

I have an Entity which is mapped to a database view and I want to avoid spring from creating table for it, I've tried @Immutable annotation but it's not working, also I want the program to create the view for entity from my script file if it's not created.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Immutable
public class ViewRequest {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private Date createDate;
    private String requestType;
    private String customerUser;
    private Long customerUserId;
    private RequestStatusEnum requestStatus;
}
```

any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend to create view in sql interface and later map it to entity from java code

Comment: @silentsudo I don't know how to do that

Comment: Special thanks to this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680504/exclude-a-specific-table-from-being-created-by-hibernate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @Subselect annotation is the only annotation in Hibernate that prevents the creation of the corresponding table for an @Entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Immutable
@Subselect("select * from VIEW_REQUEST")
public class ViewRequest {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private Date createDate;
    private String requestType;
    private String customerUser;
    private Long customerUserId;
    private RequestStatusEnum requestStatus;
}
```

Special thanks to this answer :
[Exclude a specific table from being created by hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680504/exclude-a-specific-table-from-being-created-by-hibernate)

and for the view creation, you should add your script to a file called data.sql in resources folder, and the file would be automatically executed after table updates of hibernate.[image]

Comment: `@Data` contains `@Setter`, and it is better to define the class immutable, so replace `@Data` with `@Getter` and put `@Column(insertable = false)` above the ID