# Hibernate, Spring Data: class-based projections don't work with native queries: no converter found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

**DogRepository.java**:

```java
public interface DogRepository extends JpaRepository<Dog, Long> {
...
    @Query(value = "SELECT name from dogs;", nativeQuery = true)
    List<SuperDto> withNames();
}
```

**SuperDto.java**:

```java
public class SuperDto {
    private String name;

    public SuperDto()  {
        
    }
    
    public SuperDto(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I get an exception

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type
```

Meanwhile if `SuperDto` is an `interface`:

```java
public interface SuperDto {
    String getName();
}
```

it works fine.

I realized that class-based projections don't work well with native queries.

So I tried to change the code:

```java
    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    List<SuperDto> withNames();
```

```java
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "SuperDto.withNames",
    query = "SELECT name from dogs",
    resultSetMapping = "SuperDto")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "SuperDto",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(targetClass = SuperDto.class,
        columns = {@ColumnResult(name = "name")}))
public class SuperDto {...}
```

But now I get

```
Error creating bean with name 'dogController' defined in file
```

exception.

How do I make it work with a POJO class?

Comment: you are having same name of interface and class. are they in different packages?

Comment: @JAMSHAID I changed the code in `SuperDto` for the purposes of this question. Then I changed it back to be a class

Comment: The `@ NamedNativeQuery` needs to be on the entity not on some random class. If you are using a named query also ditch the `@Query` as all the information is already derived from the named native query annotation and automatically detected.

Comment: @M.Deinum  I'm trying to adapt DTO example from this article: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/. A DTO is not supposed to be associated with a table in a database, though? While an Entity is associated with a table. Is there another way to make a concrete class DTO work with native queries?

Comment: also good ref: https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-dto-native-queries/ (+ linked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, the `@NamedNativeQuery` annotation needs to be present in an entity class(or a mapped superclass). So what I have ended up doing in the past is to make the `DTO` class a dummy entity by adding the `@Entity` annotation and a dummy `@Id` field. The `@NamedNativeQuery` and `@SqlResultSetMapping` mapping annotations can then be added to this DTO/Entity class. And whatever name is specified for the query in the `@NamedNativeQuery` annotation needs to be specified in the `@Query` annotation in the repository class. Applying the same changes in this case, I was able to get the `withNames` method working. Changes are below:

**SuperDto.java:**

```java
import org.hibernate.annotations.Subselect;

import javax.persistence.ColumnResult;
import javax.persistence.ConstructorResult;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;

@Entity
@Subselect("select * from dogs") // To prevent creation of a super_dto table
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "dog_names",
        query = "SELECT name from dogs",
        resultSetMapping = "SuperDto"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "SuperDto",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = SuperDto.class,
                columns = {
                        @ColumnResult(name = "name")
                }
        )
)
public class SuperDto {
    @Id
    private String id = "";

    private String name;

    public SuperDto()  {
        
    }
    
    public SuperDto(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**DogRepository.java:**

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import java.util.List;

public interface DogRepository extends JpaRepository<Dog, Long> {
    @Query(name = "dog_names", nativeQuery = true)
    List<SuperDto> withNames();
}
```

Comment: What bothers me about this, though, is the need for `@Entity` annotation - it not only adds the `ID` field requirement, but also prevents you from using `Set<String>` fields (without `@ElementCollection` or `@Transient` annotations). It kind of fields like a hack. Would always using an interface be a more clean way to do DTO projections?

Comment: **And** it created a `dog_names` table in my database too...

Comment: Yeah, I too can't remember for sure why I used the dummy `@Entity` instead of an interface, in the past. It sure involved less code.

Comment: Didn't realize it created a table with the query's name. Probably because in our app, table creation through JPA was disabled as our DDLs were managed using flyway outside of the app. I thought I did confirm that no additional tables were created before posting the answer. I tested against a local postgres DB. Let me check again. What DB are you using?

Comment: I use `PostgreSQL`. I've researched other options - one being using a custom repository + `ResultTransformer`. That works without an `@Entity` (or any other) annotation on a `DTO`: https://vladmihalcea.com/one-to-many-dto-projection-hibernate/. I'm curious, what would make someone use the current approach over the `ResultTransformer`?

Comment: You were right - with Postgres, an additional table was getting created, though in my case, it was named `super_dto` instead of `dog_names`. I had tested against H2 DB before and hadn't noticed this. Had to add a `@Subselect` annotation as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680504/exclude-a-specific-table-from-being-created-by-hibernate), to disable the table creation. But yeah, at this point, it does feel really hacky

Comment: As for the choice between `@SqlResultSetMapping` and `ResultTransformer`, I believe it might be a question of preference, at least it was in my case. I have extensively used myBatis before and liked its simple [result maps](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#advanced-result-maps). I was looking for a JPA equivalent of a similar mapping and ended up using `@SqlResultSetMapping`. On the other hand, if I had been used to something like Spring's `RowMapper`, I probably would have chosen the `ResultTransformer` instead.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to test it on your machine! And thank you for your opinion on `ResultTransformer`! I've decided to experiment both with approach you shown in your answer and the `ResultTransformer`! I really appreciate your help, it means a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to select all fields from the table

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT d.* from dogs d", nativeQuery = true)
```

If you need to do any mapping from column names to bean properties you'll need to alias the columns

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT d.name as dogName, d.age as dogAge, ... from dogs d", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: Selecting everything didn't work. The column in the database is called `name`, so there should be no problems on that front. I think the problem is in `NamedNativeQuery` and `SqlResultSetMapping` annotations

Answer (score 1):

The `@NamedNativeQuery` annotation can only be applied to an entity or mapped superclass, according to [the java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee%2F7%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html).

Referring to ["How to Use Named Queries with Spring Data JPA"](https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-named-queries/):

> The name doesn’t have to follow any conventions if you want to
> reference the query programmatically. But if you’re going to reference
> it in a Spring Data JPA repository, the name should start with the
> name of the entity class, followed by a “.” and the name of the
> repository method.

Therefore, the `@NamedNativeQuery` and the `@SqlResultSetMapping` annotations should be moved to the `Dog` entity class, and the named native query should be renamed to `Dog.withNames`.